# Making a datarow Select() Query

Tags: c#, asp.net

The thing is i have a data row array which contains ID and parent id as its fields.

I have used the following code and it returned the correct values ,

```
datarow [] dt = datarow.select("  Parent = '0' ");
```

I want to select only those rows which don't have the '0' as its Parent.I know sql i am not getting how the select function works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using LINQ - Here is an example to use, I think this is what you wanted:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable("Example");
  dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("ParentID", typeof(int));
  dt.Rows.Add(1, 0);
  dt.Rows.Add(1, 1);

  var equal0 = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => x.Field<int>("ParentID") == 0);
  var notEqual0 = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => x.Field<int>("ParentID") != 0);
```

You get a list of data rows with parent ids which are equal to 0 and a list which doesn't equal 0.

EDIT:

I see you are attempting Select - Where is an alternative and does what you want to do. This filters based on a bool condition so you can do where the ParentID is more than x or less than etc.

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Is it possible that we can directly `Select` or `Where` on the `DataRow[]` array instead of building a `DataTable` first?

Answer (score 1):

try this ::

```
DataRow[] dt = dt.Select("Parent != '0'");
dt[0][Your Column Name] = your value;
```